# Toolbar in Settings page built with PreferenceFragment

Tags: android, user-interface, settings, android-preferences

I built a Settings activity/screen for my app using [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) guide. Example code is bellow.
What am I missing to be able to add a Toolbar to this new activity with a back arrow in it's left side?

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
....
<activity
    android:name=".SettingsActivity"
    android:label="Settings"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
....
```

**preferences.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<CheckBoxPreference
    android:key="pref_sync"
    android:title="@string/pref_sync"
    android:summary="@string/pref_sync_summ"
    android:defaultValue="true" />
<ListPreference
    android:dependency="pref_sync"
    android:key="pref_syncConnectionType"
    android:title="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
    android:dialogTitle="@string/pref_syncConnectionType"
    android:entries="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_entries"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_syncConnectionTypes_values"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_syncConnectionTypes_default" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

**SettingsFragment.java**

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
    ...
}
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(android.R.id.content, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must include a toolbar in your activity layout. For example:

activity_main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".activities.SettingsActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

In your Activity.onCreate() get the toolbar and set a home button (the little arrow):

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Set the SettingsActivity to be a child of parent MainActivity:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.SettingsActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
    android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity" />
```

And that will give you that little arrow.

Also, do this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

Not this:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity
```

In order to use support library.

Comment: Something's wrong with the toolbar. I get a NullPointerException in getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: By "activity_main.xml" I guess you mean a separate xml for the SettingsActivity, not the MainActivity xml.
I'll call it "settings_main.xml".

Isn't setContentView(R.layout.settings_main) also needed? I added it.

I tried replacing Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar) with Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.app_bar) and the toolbar shows but it's overlapping the Settings content. I mean, "Settings" text and arrow are above the first PreferenceCategory text and the toolbar colored rectangle is invisible.

Comment: @AdrienNoir The code in my post is just for a general activity + toolbar + fragment to give you an example of how it might look. You will have to adapt it to your own needs but the important bits are 1. Specify parent in manifest 2. get the toolbar in YourActivity.onCreate() and set it so it shows the arrow. That arrow takes you back to whatever parent you specified in the toolbar. Without me looking at your app, it is kind of hard to give you more advice...