# How do I add a Toolbar to a SettingsFragment Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

Run into a situation that I'm a little bit stuck on. I've got a `root_preferences.xml` and a `SettingsFragment` and a `nav_graph`. As the title says, I want to be able to add a `Toolbar` to my `settingsFragment`, however I cannot seem to find a way of doing this.

Here's how my app is set up:

`MainFragment`:

```
private val navController by lazy { Navigation.findNavController(requireContext(), R.id.nav_host)

private var _binding: FragmentMainBinding? = null

private val binding get() = _binding!!

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: Inflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = FragmentMainBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    (activity as AppCompatActivity).setSupportActionBar(binding.mfToolbar)

    ...

    return binding.root
}

override fun onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu: Menu) {
    ...
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    when(item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> {
            navController.navigate(R.id.settingsFragment)
        }
    }
}

...
```

My `nav_graph.xml` has my `MainFragment` and my `SettingsFragment` added into it so that I'm able to see the ID string within `navController.navigate()`

Within my `SettingsFragment` I have the basic Android Studio generated layout:

```
override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)


}
```

My question here is, how do I add a Toolbar to the settings fragment so that the user can then tap the up button to go back to the last fragment?

Comment: Haven't checked but looks like [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/6zed2l/can_a_preferencefragment_have_its_own_toolbar/dmvwk8v?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) works. Try it out, it should be a quick one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Toolbar in Settings page built with PreferenceFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36898795/toolbar-in-settings-page-built-with-preferencefragment)

Comment: That is close but not quite. See, I'd need to create another activity and I want this my app to stay as a single activity. :(